# How to expand only one accordion tab at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to be able to expand only one accordion tab at a time. For example if item 1 was expanded then when expanding item 2, item 2 would expand but item 1 would collapse so that only one was expanded at a time. Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/a5uxgkmt/

The code that I have written sort of works but not fully. For example, If I expand item 1, I am not able to click and collapse item 1 directly. I will have to expand item 2 to collapse item 1, which is fine, but I want to also be able to have the option to expand and collapse an item directly.

Jquery:

```
    var collapsible = $('.accordion-toggle');
    for (var i = 0; i < collapsible.length; i++) {
        collapsible[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            for (var j = 0; j < collapsible.length; j++) {
                collapsible[j].classList.remove("collapsed")
                collapsible[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
            }
            this.classList.toggle("collapsed");
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                content.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible - you can use jquery's accordion library to do this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your fiddle following code will work

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-toggle");
for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function(evnt) {
    const currClassList = evnt.target.classList;
    if (currClassList.contains('collapsed')) {
        evnt.target.classList.remove("collapsed");
        var content = evnt.target.nextElementSibling;
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      for (var j = 0; j < coll.length; j++) {
           coll[j].classList.remove("collapsed")
           coll[j].nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = null;
      }
      this.classList.toggle("collapsed");
      var content = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.maxHeight){
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: hi @Tapas, I have tried your suggestion, but it still doesn't fix, I am not able to toggle an item by itself. Here is the fiddle that I have put: https://jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/a5uxgkmt/

Comment: Hello Cliff, based on your fiddle I have changed the solution

Comment: Hi Tapas, it's working now, thank you for the help.

Comment: hi @Tapas, I have a follow up question based on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cliffeee/a5uxgkmt/11/ . I noticed that when I put the accordion title inside a <button>  it doesn't collapse after you expand it.  But If you click anywhere around the button, then it toggles fine, however, when we click only on the button it expands, but doesn’t not collapse. Is there is way to fix this behavior?

Comment: Yes, you can replace event.target with event.currentTarget and it will start working. The reason being event.target given the pointer to element clicked and currentTarget gives the pointer to element on which event is binded. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [JQuery Accordion library](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible). This allows you to open only 1 tab at at time and also allow you to close an opened tab, just like how you wanted.

Try this:

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="accordion">
<h2>Open Collapsible</h2>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<h2>Open Section 1</h2>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Just add your css in accordingly.

Remember to link the JQuery and the accordion by adding it in your `<head>` tag.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Gosi, thanks for showing a different way of doing it!

Comment: Np @Cliff, glad it helped!